# If $J(L)=\int_{L}\frac{dz}{p(z)}$, where $p(z)$ is a polynomial with $n$ distinct roots, how many values can $J$ take on?

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers, complex-integration

My question is related to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36065/number-of-distinct-values-of-oint-gamma-fracdzz-a-1z-a-2-z-a-n), but it is not a duplicate, because I am not allowed to use Residues or Cauchy's Integral Formula to solve it. The only tools I have at my disposal are Cauchy's Theorem and Cauchy's Theorem for Multiply Connected Domains.

I need to solve the following:

> Given a polynomial $p(z) = (z-z_{1})(z-z_{2})\cdots (z-z_{n})$, where
>   $z_{k} \neq z_{j} $for $k \neq j$, let $L$ be a simple closed
>   rectifiable curve that does not pass through any of the roots of
>   $p(z)$. How many distinct values of $\int_{L}\frac{dz}{p(z)}$ can one
>   obtain, at most, by changing $L$? (In other words, the integral
>   $\int_{L}\frac{dz}{p(z)}$ is a function $J(L)$ of $L$. How many values
>   can it take on, at most?)

Using partial fraction decomposition, we know that what we would want is to have $\displaystyle \int_{L}\frac{dz}{p(z)} = \int_{L}\frac{1}{(z-z_{1})(z-z_{2})\cdots(z-z_{n})}dz = \int_{L} \frac{A_{1}}{(z-z_{1})}+\frac{A_{2}}{(z-z_{2})}+\cdots + \frac{A_{n}}{(z-z_{n})}dz$.

So, $A_{1}(z-z_{2})\cdots(z-z_{n})+A_{2}(z-z_{1})(z-z_{3})\cdots(z-z_{n})+\cdots + A_{n}(z-z_{1})(z-z_{2})\cdots(z-z_{n-1}) = 1$,

and each $\displaystyle A_{k} = \frac{1}{(z_{k}-z_{1})(z_{k}-z_{2})\cdots (z_{k}-z_{k-1})(z_{k}-z_{k+1})(z_{k}-z_{n})}$.

But, I don't know where to go from there.

The other question mentioned that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}A_{i} = 0$, which makes absolutely no sense to me. If this is true, I would welcome an explanation why.

I get that as $L$ gets larger to encompass all of the $z_{i}$ (even if the $z_{i}$ are not in order from smallest to largest, we can, WLOG, order them that way), the integral will become zero, by Cauchy's Theorem. But, this is as far as I have been able to reason.

Feel free to be extremely detailed in your answer. I am completely clueless.

Comment: Unless I have misunderstood, this will simply be $|\wp(\{ z_1,\cdots, z_n\})|-1=2^n-1$ (the $-1$ being because if all roots lie in the interior, or none, we get the same value for $J(L)$, namely $0$, as you pointed out)

Comment: @JulienGodawatta, can you please explain in more detail where this came from? Specifically the $2^{n}$ part? Again, remember, I am extremely, completely clueless.  And how to show this formally, please? Perhaps as an answer, with details, and not just as a comment.

Comment: Say $p$ has $n$ distinct roots, then $1/p$ has $n$ poles. Best case scenario, the integral around no roots, around each root, and around every pair of roots, every triplet $...$ around all $n$ roots, all yield different values. The number of these is precisely the power set of $\{z_1,\cdots,z_n\}$, which has size $2^n$. Noting that both the cases where the interior of $L$ contains all roots, and where it contains none, both give $J(L)=0$, we get $2^n-1$ possible values.

Comment: Two exceptions: degree of $p$ is $0$ or $1$, where we have respectively $1$ and $2$ possible values. This is because the interior of $L$ containing all roots $\Rightarrow J(L)=0$ is only true when $\text{deg}\,p\geqslant 2$ (and more generally, the sum of residues of the rational function $q/p$ is only $0$ when $\text{deg}\,p> \text{deg}\,q+1$)

Comment: @JulienGodawatta, is that the most rigorous way to write it?

Comment: Well, a less "wordy" way of writing that out be using residues (which are precisely the values of $J(L)$). Without this or the integral formula I cannot see how else you will answer this differently. Cauchy's theorem applies when $f$ is holomorphic inside $L$, which $1/p$ will not be unless it is constant, so the theorem is not relevant here.

Comment: More rigorous, well, I suppose you could write this as "if for each $S\subseteq \{z_1,\cdots, z_n\}$, taking $L$ such that its interior contains $S$ but not $\{z_1,\cdots,z_n\}\setminus S$, $J(L)$ takes different values, then we have at most $|\wp(\{z_1\cdots z_n\})|$ etc.". As long as your statements are clear it is rigorous enough, in my opinion.

Comment: @JulienGodawatta, actually, last night it made sense to me that if the region encompassed all the roots, the integral would be zero. Tonight it doesn't. And can you please explain the $-1$ part again?

Comment: Sure, take $C_R$, a large circle around the origin (containing all roots). Consider $\left|\int_{C_R} \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{p(z)}\right|$. By parametrising $z=Re^{i\vartheta}$, you will see that the integrand will be of order $O(R^{1-n})$ i.e. will look like $1/(R^{n-1}+\text{stuff})$. This means that $\int_{C_R}1/p$ can be made arbitrarily small by taking $R$ arbitrarily large, i.e. it must be zero (note that this relies on the fact that the value of the integral does *not* change as $R$ grows, because we do not hit any other poles)